# Is using php7 as the only web server possible?

Tags: php, webserver

While reading Symfony framework installation instructions I came across a recommendation to use php7 buit-in web server, but the same instruction suggests that php internal web server is not for production environment.

[Configuring a Web Server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

> The preferred way to develop your Symfony application is to use **PHP's
>   internal web server**. However, when using an older PHP version or when
>   running the application **in the production environment, you'll need to
>   use a fully-featured web server**. This article describes several ways
>   to use Symfony with Apache or Nginx.

I wanted to setup a test server with a minimal bundle that can serve php applications, i.e. Ubuntu 14 + PHP7 but it appears the minimal bundle is Ubuntu + Nginx + PHP7

After an hour's Google browsing, I only got thousands of articles on PHP web server usage with Apache, Nginx but there is lack of info on using PHP7 inbuilt webserver alone, **without** any other server

So is php7 alone web server possible or is it a toy or a development tool rather than production server?

Comment: It's not a fully fledged server, it's designed for development. As all the documentation tells you, you shouldn't use it for production.

Comment: Let me ask you another question in return: Would you consider a raspberry pi fit for a production environment? Apart from some features you can come to miss rather quickly (e.g. it supports only http/1.0, i.e. each request requires a completely new connection) _if_ something goes wrong (depending on what you're doing where) it can add "negligence" to _your_ problems.

Comment: @VolkerK I just need to decide where or not to consider php7 as webserver, but there is a lack of info why it is not a real web server.

Comment: The built-in web server is just a convenience and not meant to be something more than 1 person would use. I came accross [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/32pfw0/using_phps_built_in_server_in_production/) which has a discussion, of course because it is reddit it shouldn't be considered official documentation, but it has useful information in there.

Answer (score 5):

You could use **Run with built-in web server** feature of PHP.

This feature is supported since PHP 5 and using php-cli. If you want to use it in PHP 7 just install php7.0-cli.

Then you can quickly setup a web server using this command (in terminal):

```
php -S <web server address>:<port> -t <document_root>
```

Example:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t /home/public_html/public
```

And access your web using browser with that url: 127.0.0.1:8080

Also you can replace it with IP or domain name of your remote server and it still work

Hope it exactly what you need

Comment: thanks for the answer but I see no point in developing locally vs developing directly on cloud server in the same environment that the application is intended to run.

Comment: `I wanted to setup a test server with a minimal bundle that can serve php applications, i.e. Ubuntu 14 + PHP7`. If this is not what you want then please explain your question with more details. Regards,

Comment: test server is not necessarily local, you can not test production environment with your local machine, therefore, very time I develop a solution, I deploy another cloud server with exactly the same components that will be used in production environment.

Comment: Ah, maybe I wasn't clear. The example is for local environment but you can replace it with any IP address or domain name of your test server and it still work. Example: `php -S 1.2.3.4:8080` and then access it in the browser with url: 1.2.3.4:8080. Regards,

Comment: How to track get/post json request / response in console via same command. ?